# Apex / Visualforce / SOQL Performance

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am trying to improve my apex VF performance and checked various parts. I have already checked the best practice guideline for salesforce VF page. However going further I am looking is there any architecture change or behavior which can help me in improving the performance of Visualforce page which is using the Dynamic query in the backend.

Comment: Thats pretty hard to understand what kind of page do you have, and which improvements did you do already, what is realistic load. Did you already get any performance issues? Because premature optimization -- http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization

Comment: From the SFDC [Architect Core Resources](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Architect_Core_Resources) page : [Performance Tuning for Visualforce and Apex](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aYMY2VES2bY)

Comment: First rule of performance optimisation is to measure first and the developer console timeline view (see [Performance Profiling on the Force.com Platform](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2013/05/force-com-performance-profiling-using-the-developer-console.html)) could help you identify here to focus your efforts. The dynamic query may or may not be causing the performance problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are lots of things you can do to test your design and implementation but as @kurunve said this is a general question you are asking. However if your page is externally available, via a site you can run your page for load time using one of many tools such as https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/. You can view information about your page load times and total viewstate in the developer console debugger. Set the debug mode to the granularity of your preference. Client side rendering can be preferable over server side depending on what you are up to. Also, here is a nice concise slide deck on some tried and true best practices from the experts: http://www.slideshare.net/developerforce/df121306-ready